# JavaScript which worked on chrome and edge is not working on firefox

Tags: firefox

the script written to click a specific element works exactly the way it is intended to do but the same line of code is clicking another element on Firefox.

Comment: Please follow guidelines in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.